# Trying to create a timer but having some trouble with an increment method

Tags: java

This is my first post here so work with me please

I am working on a method that implements an increment function into a method to keep track of the amount of days between 2 dates. Time doesn't matter, the only technicality is that I am including leap years such that leap years do have an extra day in February. I want to do this without importing any outside time related classes.

The GeoCountDownTimer is an object containing the date.

I want to get the amount of days between 10/19/4760 and 2/6/5063 in MM/DD/YYYY format.

```
private static final int[] DAYS_IN_MONTH = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31,
            31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

private static final String[] MONTHS = {"", "January", "February",
            "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December"};

public int daysInMonth(int tempMonth) {
        int daysInMonth;
        if (isLeapYear(year))
            DAYS_IN_MONTH[2] = 29;
        daysInMonth = DAYS_IN_MONTH[tempMonth];
        return daysInMonth;
    }

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
    }
```

```
public void inc() {
        int tempDay = day;
        int tempMonth = month;
        int tempYear = year;
        int count = 0;

        daysInMonth(tempMonth);

        if (this.isValidDate()) {
            tempDay++;
            if (tempDay > DAYS_IN_MONTH[tempMonth]) {
                tempDay = 1;
                tempMonth++;
            }
            if (tempMonth == 13) {
                tempDay = 1;
                tempMonth = 1;
                tempYear++;
            }
        }

        this.day = tempDay + count;
        this.month = tempMonth;
        this.year = tempYear;
    }
```

```
public int daysToGo(String fromDate) {
        int count = 0;
        GeoCountDownTimer tempStart = new GeoCountDownTimer(fromDate);
        GeoCountDownTimer tempEnd = this;

        while (!tempStart.toString().equals(tempEnd.toString())) {
            tempStart.inc();
            count++;
        }

        return count;
    }
```

I expect to get an output of 110413 but the actual is 110642

Comment: Where are you accounting for leap years in `inc()`? Also what does `daysInMonth(tempMonth);` do? If there's any result from that method call, you're not assigning it to anything.

Comment: Does the `DAYS_IN_MONTH` array have an extra day in February on leap years? Some more of these functions in this question could be useful.

Comment: Ok those missing methods were added. Sorry this is an entire project and I’m trying not to add too much of the extra stuff